# Can rows have different column count?

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible that I can have arrays which its rows have different column count?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Eran I just updated question to help others

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have different column count for each row.

`data_type [][] array = new data_type[row][]`

`array[0] = new data_type[size1]`

`array[1] = new data_type[size2]`

P.S : Why don't you try on your system, before asking such questions.

P.P.S : Here i have assumed that `row >=2`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, here is example of iterating through them

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] numbers = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };
        for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(numbers[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

output:

```
123
1234
12345
```